# Turning iphone to an iBeacon from local notification

Tags: swift, swift3, bluetooth-lowenergy, uilocalnotification, ibeacon

I'm trying to turn my iPhone to an iBeacon, I've seen and tested it that I can do it when I open my app, but I have a question that if I can do it without unlocking the phone and simply by entering the region that there is iBeacon and then got notified on my phone when my phone is locked and then turn my phone to iBeacon just by one of the choices that I got in my notification(without unlocking my phone) so I'm just concerned if anyone knows that Bluetooth Manager and CLLocation work just when you unlocked your phone or it can be done without it.
Thanks...

Answer (score 4):

Due to iOS restrictions, your app cannot act as an iBeacon in the background, only when it is in the foreground.  The user would need to tap the notification to open your app before you can broadcast a beacon

Comment: Thanks a lot, do you know if it's possible to send a small file or specific code to a server by local notification without unlocking the phone?

Comment: Yes, as long as the user taps one of the actions on the notification you should be able to do that.

Comment: @Thanks for your respond